# Error when executing SQLCommand using C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, ado.net, sql-server-ce

i'm pretty new to ADO.NET using C# (Visual Studio 2010). Using LinqToSql isn't an option because underlying database is a Compact Edition 3.5 (unfortunealty).

with the code displayed underneath I get an error: "There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 2,Token line offset = 38,Token in error = AgentName ]"

Can someone tell me what i'm doing wrong?

```
 using (SqlCeConnection oConn = new SqlCeConnection(connectionstring))
        {
            string strSql = @"select 
                        a.name as 'AgentName',
                        t.description as 'JobType',
                        s.description as 'Status',
                        count(j.statusid) as 'Count'
                    from 
                        jobs as j 
                            inner join agents as a on j.agentid = a.id
                            inner join statusdictionary as s on j.statusid = s.id
                            inner join jobtypedictionary as t on j.jobtypeid = t.id
                    where 
                        convert(datetime,starttime,0) between @FirstDate and @LastDate 
                        AND j.JobTypeID = @JobTypeID AND j.AgentID = @AgentID
                    group by 
                        s.description, 
                        t.description, 
                        a.name order by a.name,     
                        t.description";
            SqlCeCommand oCmd = new SqlCeCommand(strSql, oConn);

            SqlCeParameter fdparam = new SqlCeParameter();
            fdparam.ParameterName = "@FirstDate";
            fdparam.Value = firstdate;
            oCmd.Parameters.Add(fdparam);

            SqlCeParameter ldparam = new SqlCeParameter();
            ldparam.ParameterName = "@LastDate";
            ldparam.Value = lastdate ;
            oCmd.Parameters.Add(ldparam);

            SqlCeParameter JIDparam = new SqlCeParameter();
            JIDparam.ParameterName = "@JobTypeID";
            JIDparam.Value = jobtypeid;
            oCmd.Parameters.Add(JIDparam);

            SqlCeParameter AIDparam = new SqlCeParameter();
            AIDparam.ParameterName = "@AgentID";
            AIDparam.Value = jobtypeid;
            oCmd.Parameters.Add(AIDparam);

            oConn.Open();
            SqlCeDataReader oReader = oCmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: Did you try to execute the query without column aliases or did you try to change the aliases to 'col1', 'col2', ...?

Comment: Linq to SQL works with SQL Server Compact 3.5 (using sqlmetal.exe from command line)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i think you need to lose the quotes around 'AgentName'.

Answer (score 1):

Change single quotes '' to brackets []

> a.name as [AgentName],